# Filter window with dplyr: find matching row, and keep subsequent N rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe and I would like to filter out rows that match some condition, and the subsequent N rows following it. For example, consider a data frame which contains a hour and minutes column (representing a timestamp per row). Let's say I would like the first two records **after** the 0th and 6th hour. Is it possible to do this in a nice way?

```
set.seed(3)
df <- 
    data.frame(hour = 0:11, minutes = runif(12, 0, 59), count = rpois(12, 3)) %>%
    arrange(hour, minutes)
```

which produces

```
> df
   hour   minutes count
1     0  9.914450     3
2     1 47.643468     3
3     2 22.711599     5
4     3 19.336325     5
5     4 35.523940     1
6     5 35.659249     4
7     6  7.353373     5
8     7 17.381455     2
9     8 34.078985     2
10    9 37.227777     0
11   10 30.208938     1
12   11 29.796411     1
```

The normal filter returns two rows:

```
> df %>%
+     filter(hour%%6 == 0)
  hour  minutes count
1    0 9.914450     3
2    6 7.353373     5
```

However, the answer should be:

```
  hour   minutes count
1    0  9.914450     3
2    1 47.643468     3
3    6  7.353373     5
4    7 17.381455     2
```

In this case it is possible to use modulo arithmetic on the column used for filtering, but in the general case this may not possible.

The original example is provided below, where by here I wanted the first two records in each hour. In this case, Akrun's answer is good and exploits the group structure in the data.
E.g.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(0)
df <- 
    data.frame(hour = rep(0:11, 3), minutes = runif(36, 0, 59), count = rpois(36, 3)) %>%
    arrange(hour, minutes)
```

looks like:

```
   hour    minutes count
1     0  7.4077507     2
2     0 10.4168484     3
3     0 52.9051348     4
4     1 15.6650111     4
5     1 15.7660195     5
6     1 40.5343480     4
7     2 21.9553101     1
8     2 22.6621194     4
9     2 22.7807315     2
10    3  0.7900297     3
11    3 33.7983484     4
12    3 45.4206438     3
...
```

One could do

```
df %>% mutate(is_even_hour = ifelse(hour %% 2 == 0, 1, 0)) %>%
    filter(is_even_hour == 1) %>%
    group_by(hour, is_even_hour) %>%
    filter(row_number() <= 2) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-is_even_hour)
```

which gives

```
hour   minutes count
   <int>     <dbl> <int>
1      0  7.407751     2
2      0 10.416848     3
3      2 21.955310     1
4      2 22.662119     4
5      4 22.560889     2
6      4 29.364255     5
7      6 20.080591     2
8      6 53.004991     3
9      8 35.374384     4
10     8 38.987070     3
11    10  3.645390     4
12    10 10.986838     5
```

Comment: Regarding you new edit, the rules are not clear

Comment: Ok. Let me try again!

Comment: Now, I understand, but this is a totally different condition than the one you originally posted, right

Comment: Yes it is, hence my apology to you under your answer. :|

Comment: why I am saying is that your original question seems to be to modify your code to simple case and if you apply the same code in your post on the new example, it will not give the expected

Comment: Sorry, I have to leave now, will check later

Comment: Would you always need only two records or it may change to say 4, 5 ?

Comment: It might change, the choice of two was just to simplify the example.

Comment: @Alex Did you removed the new dataset or replaced it.  Please let us know when you are done with editing as your rules numbers keep on changing

Comment: I replaced it as I feel like this new example is clearer. I am done with the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'hour', we can do this in a single `filter` step

```
df %>%
     group_by(hour) %>%
     filter(!hour%%2 & row_number() <3)
#     hour   minutes count
#    <int>     <dbl> <int>
#1      0  7.407751     2
#2      0 10.416848     3
#3      2 21.955310     1
#4      2 22.662119     4
#5      4 22.560889     2
#6      4 29.364255     5
#7      6 20.080591     2
#8      6 53.004991     3
#9      8 35.374384     4
#10     8 38.987070     3
#11    10  3.645390     4
#12    10 10.986838     5
```

---

For the updated post

```
i1 <- df %>% 
          filter(hour%%6 == 0) %>%
          .$hour %>% 
          rep(., each =2)+ 0:1 %>% 
          match(., df$hour) 
df[i1,]
#   hour   minutes count
#1    0  9.914450     3
#2    1 47.643468     3
#7    6  7.353373     5
#8    7 17.381455     2
```

---

Or this can be done in a compact way with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, rep(which(!hour%%6), each = 2) + 0:1 ]]
#   hour   minutes count
#1:    0  9.914450     3
#2:    1 47.643468     3
#3:    6  7.353373     5
#4:    7 17.381455     2
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just realised that I need this 'window' ability for a more general case. I will make an edit to the question, sorry about that!

Comment: @Alex Anyway, in your code, you are removing `is_even_hour` later, so I don't know about the general case you are talking about.

Comment: see edit, some hours only contain 1 row, in that case I want this row, plus the next one from the next hour.

Comment: The solution with `data.table` seems to be the most concise, followed by base `R` with indexing.

Answer (score 3):

I could think of this `base R` solution using `sapply`.

Basically, the idea is to find out indices which are completely divisible by 6 and then using `seq` to generate next indices to be selected.

So here as you want 2 rows after every index `length.out` is 2, if in future you want more (as mentioned in the comments) you can change this to whatever number you want.

```
y <- which(df$hour%%6 == 0)
df[sapply(y, function(x) seq(x, length.out = 2)), ]

#    hour minutes   count
#1    0  9.914450      3
#2    1  47.643468     3
#7    6  7.353373      5
#8    7  17.381455     2
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible simple solution (with implementations in base R, dplyr & data.table):

```
# with base R:
df[which(df$hour %% 6 < 2),]

# with dplyr:
df %>% filter(hour %% 6 < 2)

# with data.table:
setDT(df)[which(df$hour %% 6 < 2)]
# or with .I instead of 'which':
setDT(df)[df[,.I[hour %% 6 < 2]]]
```

As @Alex righfully pointed out, the above solution will not give the correct output when there is for example no 7th hour. You can adapt the code with the `rep`and `+ 0:1` method that @akrun showed:

```
# with base R:
df[rep(which(df$hour %% 6 == 0), each = 2) + 0:1,]

# with dplyr (works also with 'filter' instead of 'slice'):
df %>% slice(rep(which(hour %% 6 == 0), each = 2) + 0:1)

# with data.table
setDT(df)[df[, rep(.I[hour %% 6 == 0], each = 2) + 0:1]]
```

Comment: This works because of modular arithmetic. In general modulo arithmetic methods may not apply.

Comment: @Alex Why not? All answers rely on modular arithmetic. So I don't see why this might be a problem.

Comment: that is a good point, however the other answers do not rely on modular arithmetic to identify the 2nd record in each window. That is what I meant by not using modular arithmetic, in the sense that the first row in each window could be identified by `df$hour %in% c(0,6)`. Further, if there was no row containing a 7th hour your answer will no longer work.

Comment: @Alex You are correct that it doesn't work when there is for example no 7th hour. I updated the answer, but you should accept one of the other two answers imo as they provided a correct solution right away and the adapted method was inspired by akrun.